# Ng2 ChartData filled with observable

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I want to fill my NG2 diagram with different values ​​from an observable. With the following code I can get the IDs that I use as labels.

The next step is to calculate an average value using the values ​​behind the IDs. There is a problem with that. The data is made available by the observable as a string []. The ChartData (number) cannot be filled with it so easily. Is there a way to cast the data into a number within this call?

```js
public ChartData: ChartDataSets [] = [
  {data: [], label: 'Average'},
];
this.tasks.pipe(
  map(x => x.map(x => x.name))
).subscribe((result => this.ChartData.data = result)); // -> TS2322: Type 'string [ ] 'is not assignable to type' ChartDataSets [] '.
```

But if that works there is still the problem that I have to add a sum over the values ​​and divide it by the number of results.
Can I even solve this problem with NG2 charts and the observable or do I have to write an additional module that calculates the average for me?

Answer (score 0):

You can cast a string to a number (assuming its actually a number) using `parseInt(value, base)` so in your case it would look something like

```js
public ChartData: ChartDataSets [] = [
  {data: [], label: 'Average'},
];
this.tasks.pipe(
  map(x => x.map(x => parseInt(x.name, 10)))
).subscribe((result => this.ChartData.data = result));
```